# Packaging SharePoint 2013 List, Site, and Reusable Workflow and How to Deploy the Package

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

How to deploy a List workflow (not reusable) which is created in SharePoint designer 2013 to another site collection without recreating it again? I have got [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2012/08/30/packaging-list-site-and-reusable-workflow-and-how-to-deploy-the-package.aspx) link which is a good post about this issue. I have tried whatever is mentioned in the post. The workflows get deployed  successfully and can also be seen in SharePoint designer 2013, but when I click on it gives an error. Anyone any ideas about it?[image]

Comment: Please check whether Windows Workflow manager is installed in that server.Then only you can run workflows in SharePoint 2013 platform. You can verfiy this by trying to create a new workflow in that site collection and check whether you can see SharePoint 2013 Workflow option while creating the workflow.